# Is the dual space of a Banach space Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Is there any counterexamples for that? or there is quick proof?

Comment: In what topology?

Answer (score 9):

The dual of Banach space is a Banach space, hence Hausdorff.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

normed => metric => Hausdorff

Answer (score 2):

For $X^*$ to be Hausdorff in the weak topology, or even the weak* toplogy, it is enougn to know that the elements of $X$ separate points of $X^*$.  But that is just the definition of equality for functions.

Given two distinct points $f,g \in X^*$, there is $x \in X$ so that $f(x) \ne g(x)$, and from this we get two disjoint open neighborhoods $\{k \in X^*: k(x) > r\}$ and $\{k \in X^*: k(x) < r\}$ where $r$ is chosen between $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

Comment: This does not work in the complex case though.

Comment: Complex case: $\mathrm{Re }f(x) \ne  \mathrm{Re }g(x)$ or $\mathrm{Im }f(x) \ne  \mathrm{Im }g(x)$ so use that.

Comment: It's easier than that. The source for the initial topology is point-separating, and it is a general fact that an initial topology with point-separating source is Hausdorff.